# predict_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I try to get predictions from my model

```
Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_set, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
```

but I get this error:

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-108-5d98c5cefe85> in <module>
----> 1 Y_pred = model.predict_generator(test_set, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
      2 
      3 #y_pred = np.where(prediction>0.5, 1, 0)
      4 
      5 y_pred = np.argmax(Y_pred, axis=1)

TypeError: predict_generator() got an unexpected keyword argument 'batch_size'
```

what should be possible ways to run the code without any error?

Answer (score 1):

Using `model.predict` instead of `model.predict_generator` fixes the problem
Therefore your code should be:

```
Y_pred = model.predict(test_set, batch_size=128, verbose=0)
```